# Dynamic Multilevel Drop-down menu in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii-extensions, yii-components

I want to create a dynamic menu with my table (db). I have followed some instructions which are given below:

Table : "menupanal"

[image: Table : "menupanal"]

Step 01: I just create a super controller in app\components\Controller.php

Here is the code:

```
    namespace app\components;

use app\models\MenuPanal;

class Controller extends \yii\web\Controller
{

    public $menuItems = [];

    public function init(){

     $items = MenuPanal::find()
        ->where(['c_type'  => 'MENU'])
        ->orderBy('id')
        ->all();


     $menuItems = [];
     foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
                 $this->menuItems[] = 
                      ['label' => $value['c_name'], 
                          'items'=> [
                              ['label' => $value['c_redirect'], 'url' => ['#']],
                          ],
                      ];    
            }

  parent::init();
}
```

Step 02: Changed n main layout page:

```
        echo Nav::widget([
            'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],

            'items' => Yii::$app->controller->menuItems,
        ]);
```

It is working in only one level. My question::

**Question : how can I add multilevel menu using Super controller ?**

I am new in Yii2. Helps are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create New MenuHelper in Component folder. There is no default component folder. Please create by yourself.

   ```
   <?php

   namespace app\components;

   use app\models\MenuPanel;
   use app\models\Zuser;
   use app\models\Vwrole;
   use app\assets\AppAsset;


   class MenuHelper
   {

       public static function getMenu()
       {
           $role_id = 1;
           $result = static::getMenuRecrusive($role_id);
           return $result;
       }

       private static function getMenuRecrusive($parent)
       {

           $items = MenuPanel::find()
               ->where(['c_parentid' => $parent])
               ->orderBy('c_sortord')
               ->asArray()
               ->all();

           $result = []; 

           foreach ($items as $item) {
               $result[] = [
                       'label' => $item['c_name'],
                       'url' => ['#'],
                       'items' => static::getMenuRecrusive($item['id']),
                       '<li class="divider"></li>',
                   ];
           }
           return $result;
       }

   }
   ```
2. in Main Layout Page put the following code

   ```
       echo Nav::widget([
           'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
           'items' => app\components\MenuHelper::getMenu(),
   ```

Enjoy Coding!!

Answer (score 1):

You may use nested sets. Look at this extension for Yii: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/nestedsetbehavior/ and its documentation. All you need to do is component with dynamic creation of menu items array for nested sets.

I found that there is a Yii2 extension version: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-nestedsetbehavior/

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You may use this extension for multilevel dropdown[Multi level Dropdown](http://demos.krajee.com/dropdown-x)